# binary tree node count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to count A (BC,F,G,G). ie `A` has 5 children in left for left side of `A`

```
      A                           B                           F

   b        D               F            G

 C             E
```

My Table structure is:

```
MAIN         CHILD           SIDE              POSTION
A            NULL            NULL              0
A            B               LEFT              1
A            D               RIGHT             1
B            F               LEFT              1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) To format code, just use the code `{ }` button in the toolbar to format your code. Also, please do not write in all caps. (It is usually perceived negatively, as if you are "shouting" or are angry about something ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but is it something like this?

```
select count(*) from (select child_id from my_table group by child_id)
```

This will return the count of nodes that have a parent (i.e. are children of any node).

Comment: i want to count the child of left side

Comment: Sorry, is not clear what you're asking here. Try to edit your question and include more details on what you need.